# Error launching Phoenix on Hbase

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I installed Phoenix in my system and copied phoenix-4.10.0-HBase-0.98-server.jar to the Hbase lib directory.Then I restarted Hbase. If i try to execute sqlline.py to launch phoenix Hbase it throws below error. Please Advise

[image]

Comment: add the port. localhost:8765

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: are you intending to use the Phoenix Query Server?

Comment: I am trying to launch phoenix over hbase to index some of the tables in hbase.Just an academic project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after I reinstalled hbase .